# install pandas in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I can´t install pandas for python 3.7 windows 10
this is the message

```
C:\Users\PATRICIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip3 install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/01/803834bc8a4e708aedebb133095a88a4dad9f45bbaf5ad777d2bea543c7e/pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Cython
```

Comment: python 3.7 is still in beta and most likely is that the developers of the libraries like pandas do not use that version, I recommend using version other than alpha or betas

Comment: That being said, perhaps the Pandas maintainers know about this. You should check there.

Answer (score 3):

Supported version list update as of 06 July 2018:

> Officially Python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7

---

From the Current [DOCS](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#python-version-support):

#### Python version support

> Officially Python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6.

Comment: At the time of writing (24 Sep 2018), 3.7 is also officially supported.

Comment: Another update, currently Python 3.7 is no longer supported. But 3.7.1 is.